# Плагин CSS для Sublime Text 3

Tags: css, css3, sublime-text, text

Здравствуйте! Можно ли как-то сделать в Sublime Text 3, что-бы при написании свойства css в подсказке выдавало список всех возможных значений для него? Если это можно сделать с помощью плагина, напишите плс название.

Comment: Их много. Навскидку, которыми часто пользуюсь: Emmet, Hayaku, CSS Snippets, Sublime Web Colors, CSSFontFamily. Искать любые пакеты под свои запросы пробуйте на [**сайте Package Control**](https://packagecontrol.io/search/css), в данном случае по ключевому слову `CSS`. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Для этого установите CCS3.

**Для установки:**

1. Откройте командную строку Sublime сочетанием клавиш "CTRL+SHIFT+P"
2. Введите команду "Package Control: Install Package" и нажмите Enter
3. Введите название пакета "CSS3" и нажмите Enter

**Далее необходимо отключить пакет "CSS". Для этого:**

1. Откройте командную строку Sublime сочетанием клавиш "CTRL+SHIFT+P"
2. Введите команду "Package Control: Disable Package" и нажмите Enter
3. Введите название пакета "CSS" и нажмите Enter

Далее необходимо установить CCS3 в качестве языка по умолчанию для .css файлов. Для этого открываем любой .css файл и выбираем из меню View → Syntax → Open all with current extension as… → CSS3

***Обратите внимание:***

По умолчанию при вводе значения появляется список значений
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же список значений можно вызвать сочетанием клавиш "CTRL+SPACE"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **1.** Не рекомендовал бы использовать CSS3, в дефолтном CSS синтаксисе уже больше возможностей. Когда я писал [**цветовую схему**](http://kristinita.ru/Sublime-Text/SashaSublime#css), то обнаруживал, что в CSS3 относительно бедный синтаксис, почему отказался от его поддержки. // **2.** Отключать пакет `CSS` необязательно, если установим другой синтаксис для `css` файлов. // **3.** Ну и на мой взгляд неправильно упоминать в ответе только про один пакет, когда их множество (см. мой комментарий к вопросу). // Спасибо.